# Meteor server-side redirection when new user is created

Tags: meteor

I want to redirect when a new user account has been created.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
// what to do?
})
```

I am using `iron:router` but `Router.go()` doesn't work because it's only for the client. Iron Router is said to support server-side redirection but in this case, I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: `Router.route('/login',function(){
         Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
          this.render('whateheverRoute')
          return user;
        })
    })` try putting the function inside the `Router.route`

Comment: What if `/login` doesn't exist because it happens from a modal that's contained in a navigation bar?

Comment: but you should have that navbar inside some template, so just put that this.render there, the key here is that you can use the context of this.render inside any of the hooks, functions iron router have

Comment: sorry could you elaborate more? I am using a Bootstrap modal so I don't actually have anything for the `Nav` template inside the router file. That's why I am confused where I should place `Accounts.onCreateUser` especially because it's a server-side only code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own method in client code that calls a server method which will call Accounts.createUser. If the method succeeds you can then perform a redirect. e.g

```
       //client method
        Meteor.call('createUser', userObj, function(err,data) {
          if (err) {
          //account creation failed
          } else {
          //success, redirect
          Router.go('routeName');
        }
        });


        //server code
        Meteor.methods({
          createUser: function(user) {
            //account creation
            Accounts.createUser(user);
          }
        });
```

Comment: I must use `loginWithGoogle` function

Comment: Isn't your question related to creating an account though? Can I have some more info on how you intend it to work?

Comment: Certainly :) When the user first visits the website, he would click "login with google" and onCreateUserAccount will be called from the server side, and he should be redirected to a welcome page. If he's a returning user, `onCreateUserAccount` event won't be called and he shouldn't be redirected.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case have you used an onBeforeAction hook for the route? It should reactively show either the welcome or loginwithgoogle sections depending if a user is logged in. I'm assuming if the loginWithGoogle function logs the user in afterwards that should automatically render the welcome page without you having to redirect.